# Create a pivot table for Month over Month variation

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have these records returned from a query

```
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| Country | other fields |   sales   |   date   |
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| US      | 1            |  $100.00  | 01/01/21 |
| CA      | 1            |  $100.00  | 01/01/21 |
| UK      | 1            |  $100.00  | 01/01/21 |
| FR      | 1            |  $100.00  | 01/01/21 |
| US      | 1            |  $200.00  | 01/02/21 |
| CA      | 1            |  $200.00  | 01/02/21 |
| UK      | 1            |  $200.00  | 01/02/21 |
| FR      | 1            |  $200.00  | 01/02/21 |
```

And I want to show the sales variation from one month to previous, like this:

```
| Country | 01/02/21     | 01/01/21  | Var%     |
| US      |  $200.00     |  $100.00  | 100%     |
| CA      |  $200.00     |  $100.00  | 100%     |
| FR      |  $200.00     |  $100.00  | 100%     |
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

How could be done with a Postgres query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you always comparing two month only :

```
select country
    , sum(sales) filter (where date ='01/01/21')  month1
    , sum(sales) filter (where date ='01/02/21')  month2
    , ((sum(sales) filter (where date ='01/02/21') /sum(sales) filter (where date ='01/01/21')) - 1) * 100 var
from tablename
where date in ('01/01/21' , '01/02/21')
group by country
```

you also can look at `crosstab` from tablefunc extension which basically does the same as above query.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

select * ,("01/02/21" /"01/01/21") - 1) * 100 var 
from(
select * from crosstab ('select Country,date , sales from tablename')
as ct(country varchar(2),"01/01/21" money , "01/02/21" money)
) t
```

for more info about crosstab , see [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/tablefunc.html)

but if you want to show date in rows instead of columns, you can easily generalize it for all the dates :

```
select * 
   , ((sales / LAG(sales,1,1) over (partition by country order by date)) -1)* 100  var
from 
country
```

Comment: Could you show me how to do it with crontab from tablefunc?

Comment: @sparkle , see updated answer , also I meant 'crosstab'. was working with crontab on the same time , I got them confused :D

Comment: Any way how I could make dates dynamic instead of hard-coded in the query? Because, in this way, I have to first check if there are two months of data and data extract the result. I could have only one month of data and in this case the %var would be zero.

Comment: You have to go with dynamic sql